# How to remove empty space from the menu bar

Tags: joomla

I am working on Joomla. I am facing following issue: I want to remove the empty space after Contact Us in the Menu Bar. Now if I will add another option like any article then it automatically comes in the second row after the empty space . So i want to remove this empty space. I am unable to add the screenshot here as im a newbie.

There is a empty space on the menu bar and i want to remove that

Comment: It is not really clear from your question what causes the empty space at the end of the menu. Try to right click and use Inspect element to understand what is causing the empty space. There is probably some margin or padding causing it, and you need to modify your css to get rid of it.

Comment: <a href="http://imgur.com/OlXcH5d"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/OlXcH5d.png" title="source: imgur.com" /></a>

Comment: Hey please visit this link: I want to remove the empty space at the end of the bar